# if else condition inside function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am new in javascript my code is given below. According to conditions code should print "Get some more shut eye!" but shows syntax error , dont know whereis the mistake.

```
var sleepCheck = function (numHours)
    {
     if (number of sleep >= 8) 
    {return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";}
    else(number of sleep < 8)
    {return "Get some more shut eye!";}
    }
    sleepCheck(10);
```

Comment: Use correct variable `if(numHours >= 8){}` and closing brace is missing, seems you really some sleep :)

Comment: I think this is the time to refer the syntaxes of javascript.

Comment: Thanks for help and comment too #Satpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use `else without statement` or `else if` for your `else(number of sleep < 8)`

**else if**

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
  if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
  } else if(numHours < 8) {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
  }
}
sleepCheck(10);
```

**else**

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
  if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
  } else {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
  }
}
sleepCheck(10);
```

Comment: it's fixed , Thanks Carsten Løvbo Andersen

Comment: Your welcome @Anilkashyap , if you found this help full feel free to up vote, and if this solved your problem please mark as answered so other people might know the solution to the problem in case they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need another if

```
} else if (numHours < 8) {
//     ^^                   if missing
//        ^^^^^^^^^         wrong variable name, with spaces
```

and the right use of the variable name

```
numHours
```

instead of `number of sleep`.

```js
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8) {
    //  ^^^^^^^^
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    } else if (numHours < 8) {
    //     ^^  ^^^^^^^^
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
}
console.log(sleepCheck(10));
```

When the alternative is only the inverted check, then you could omit the second check, because

```
(numHours >= 8) === !(numHours < 8)
```

```js
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8) {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    } else {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
}
console.log(sleepCheck(10));
```